# Qt C++: How to make a for loop until a button is pressed

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have been trying to make a GUI Blackjack game in C++ with Qt. However, I have hit a road block on my way. I made the game and the game logic last year in pure C++ (link below). I am trying to use the same code to build the GUI version of the game [Github/Blackjack](https://github.com/anmolsbrar/BlackJack/tree/master/BlackJack).

It's mostly done to the point that I have the cards showing up, adding the values of those cards, the dealer and the player set up.

In the C++ version I made a vector of all the players and added the dealer to the end of it, then using a for loop, I would iterate through the players to get them to play.

In Qt, I have created a widget with two buttons "Hit" and "Stand" for the player control.
"Hit" button is simple and connected the click event of the button with the hit member function of the player.

```
        ctrl = new PlayerControl(nullptr, mainPlayer);
        connect(ctrl->ui->hitButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [mainPlayer]{
            mainPlayer->hit();
        });
```

Code for iterating through the vector:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < players.size(); i++)
            {
                if (i == playerPos - 1)
                {
                    ctrl->setVisible(true);
                    //how to make the loop to pause here until the user presses the 
                    //"Stand button", and then proceed with the rest of the loop?

                }
                else if (i == players.size() - 1)
                    dealerPlay();
                else
                    computerPlay(players[i]);
            }
```

I'll really appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the code you are showing or how it relates to the question in the title of your post.  I'll just answer the question, which is:

> How to make a for loop until a button is pressed

The answer is that you probably don't want to do that, because that would involve multi-threading or some kind of complicated concurrency mechanism.  When you're writing a GUI, the main thread of your application usually sits in a loop waiting for event messages (like clicks and key presses) from the operating system.  When it gets such a message, it is supposed to handle them quickly and then go back to waiting for the next message.

In Qt, you can handle these events by overriding functions in your QMainWindow class or by connecting Qt signals to slots.

So, instead of having a loop that iterates through each player and waits for them to make their move, you would have some long-living variables that keep track of the state of the game, and when you detect that a player has made a move (i.e. by clicking a button), you would update those variables, update any data shown on the screen, and then return from your event handler so you can handle the next event.